# PHP Query Dies In Traffic

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently in the process of testing a registration page for a project, and I've run into a problem that's kinda concerning. In short, the user enters their information on the first screen, and confirms their information and their appointment date on the following screens. On the final screen, the following function is called.

`function createRecord($id,$lname,$fname,$address1,$address2,$city,$state,$zip,$email,$homephone,$cellphone)
{
    include 'dbconnect.php'; 
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM nso1_students WHERE id = " . $id;
    $result = $db->query($sql) or die("Error performing an internal check. Error: " . mysql_error());
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($db) <= 0) //This first query checks to make sure that the student's information isn't already in the database. ID is a primary key, so it should reject a duplicate entry, but I'd rather prevent it entirely.
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO nso1_students(psuid, lname, fname, address1, address2, city, state, zip, email, 
        homephone, cellphone) VALUES (" . $psuid . ", '" . $lname . "', '" . $fname . "',
        '" . $address1 . "', '" . $address2 . "', '" . $city . "', '" . $state . "', '" . $zip . "', 
        '" . $email . "', " . $homephone . ", " . $cellphone . ")";
        $db->query($sql) or die("Error creating student record. Error: " . mysql_error()); 
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "alert('This student already has an appointment!');window.location.href='index.php';";
    }
}`

The problem I'm having is that when multiple people tested this at the same time, about 3 of 5 died at the second query, with no MySQL error being displayed. The rest went through with no trouble. I'm nowhere near experienced enough to diagnose what's going wrong in this instance, and I need some advice at this point. If there's anything else you need me to provide to answer this, please let me know.

Comment: Hi i am quite sure  '" . $homephone . "','" . $cellphone . "')"; if persome make a space in a phone number that is normal the query fails

Comment: Be advised also that you are wide open to SQL injection doing it this way.

Comment: For starters, possible mysql injection issue. You should really be using msyqli/pdo and binding your queries. Second, I see the homephone and cellphone don't have quotes around them. I hope they are not integers in the database. And if someone leaves off one of those numbers or enters common punctuation/spaces, the query would fail. Check your web server error logs (linux/debian/ubuntu default to `/var/log/apache2/error.log`) to see what the issue is. Even if they aren't getting an error, if an error is thrown it will be written to the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i am quite sure '" . $homephone . "','" . $cellphone . "')"; if persome make a space in a phone number that is normal the query fails, try it like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO nso1_students(psuid, lname, fname, address1, address2, city, state, zip, email, 
        homephone, cellphone) VALUES (" . $psuid . ", '" . $lname . "', '" . $fname . "',
        '" . $address1 . "', '" . $address2 . "', '" . $city . "', '" . $state . "', '" . $zip . "', 
        '" . $email . "', '" . $homephone . "', '" . $cellphone . "')";
```

And please take care about security, your code is sql injection pron